# displaying a spinner when we make an ajax call and waiting for the response and blocking the page 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, block

I have a page with multiple ajax call to load a part from the response ...Now I have to show a spinner on the part from which I am making an ajax call waiting for the content to get loaded...How can I have a common method which will take a parameter as a selector for the part  from which I am making an ajax call and blocking the page background

thank for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 3):

my code for that:

```
$.fn.ajaxConvertLink = function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var wrap = $(this).parent();
        if (!wrap.hasClass('spinner')) {
            wrap.addClass('spinner');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#content_for_layout').html(data);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    wrap.removeClass('spinner');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
};
```

it adds class spinner (which in css is described with a background spinner image) to parent element (but can be easly changed to alter `a` itself or completely other element)

```
<a href="/foo/bar" id="xxx'>YYY</a>
```

execute:

```
$('#xxx').ajaxConvertLink();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/2dAyf/

Comment: thanks but is it really necessary to make it as a jquery plugin  instead if i want to include inside my own namespace as MY.ajaxConvertLink = (function(){ var default={}, config = $({}, default, config); return function(config){....}; ());

Comment: This approach is great but but i don't have access to the content or its response ...i just have to display that spinner when there is a delay in ajax response ...

Answer (score 1):

You could write a proxy around the jQuery.ajax method. We'll add some simple markup (that you can style elsewhere) to the elements whose contents are being loaded, then replace that markup with the responseText once the request has completed:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

    // usage: $(<selector>).spinnerload(); 
    spinnerload: function(url, options)
    {   
        var self = this;
        var options = options || {};
        var success = options.success || function() {};

        options.success = function(responseText, status, jqXHR)
        {
            self.html(responseText);
            success(responseText, status, jqXHR);
        }

        self.html('<div class="loading"></div>');
        jQuery.ajax(url, options);
    }

});
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or any sample ?