# jQuery getter/setter conditional?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script that needs to set one of two json data call URLs depending on which element was clicked to invoke the query.

How can I code the url: property so that its determined by which element was clicked?

Off the top of my head, I was thinking to create a hidden input field and set a flag that I can read/write to depending on the link that's clicked. Then i can wrap the url: parameter in an if/then

However, then I remembered that jQuery has an each() method that I might be able to use.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
<div id='items'>
    Label: 
    <a href='#' id='item1'>Item 1</a>
    <a href='#' id='item2'>Item 2</a>
</div>

jQuery("#items").find("a").each.click(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType: "json",

    if(jQuery(this).id = '#item1')
    {
    url: "first url"
    }
    else
    {
    url: "second url"
    }       
});
```

Comment: Why not just handle this on the backend? Pass your ID as a parameter value, in your PHP code check what the value is and return appropriately? You could simplify your backend code as well, just call include 2 seperate PHP files and call a function in the correct one depending on the parameter passed. That way you have 1 url for both cases and still have 2 different PHP files for each call. I would not recommend your current approach since if you added an other item in the future you would a) add to html, (b) add to JS, (C) add to backend. This way at least you remove one dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(this.id == 'item1')
    var url = "first url";
else
    var url = "second url";
```

and then use like that:

```
{ url: $url }
```

but as for links, I would suggest:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function(data) {
                ...
            },
        });
```

like: [displaying a spinner when we make an ajax call and waiting for the response and blocking the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003339/displaying-a-spinner-when-we-make-an-ajax-call-and-waiting-for-the-response-and-b/7003352#7003352)

Comment: If you use the href value to store a url, then make sure you call event.preventDefault() to avoid actually following the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator:

```
url: this.id == 'item1' ? "first" : "second",
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an attribute:

```
<div id='items'>
    Label: 
    <a href='#' id='item1' data-url="page1.html">Item 1</a>
    <a href='#' id='item2' data-url="page2.html">Item 2</a>
</div>
```

Then use the jQuery data() function to retrieve it.

```
jQuery('#items a').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: $(this).data("url")
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using anchors, I would suggest giving the anchor the proper url and then have jQuery fetch $(this).attr('href').

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch things out at runtime:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="link">Item 1</a>
<a href="http://www.bing.com/" class="link">Item 2</a>
```

Then your script would look like this:

```
$('.link').each(function()
{
     var currentHref = this.href;

     // Unset the value so when people click on it, they dont leave the page
     // jQuery 1.6
     $(this).prop('href', '#');
     // Other Versions
     $(this).attr('href', '#');

     $(this).click(function()
     {
         // Do Ajax Call. The URL of the link is contained within `currentHref` which is contained in this scope via closure. 
     });
});
```

This way, the javascript just rearranges the data contained in the link at runtime.